# Vim status bar prediction/completion?

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I played with some vim scripting yesterday and managed to get some over-the-status-bar prediction to whatever I'm typing at the moment, with  cycling - see screenshot (gray + yellow bar).

Problem is, I can't remember how I got that or find the code snippet I used for that vim magic (I remember it being quite simple): it was either an example in the docs or something I picked up in the vim wiki. So, I'm trying to retrace my steps - any clue on what vimscript function/s to look up for these? I realize this is an odd question, but any clues will be great - thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is done with

```
:set wildmenu
```

When you press `<Tab>` while typing in the command line, completion options will appear above.

Comment: Nice! Never knew about this. Added to my vimrc =)